# OperationalError at /class101/ (1054, "Unknown column 'group20.student_id' in 'field list'") - how to fix it?

Tags: django, django-models

Guys i have problem linking ForeignKey to my models.

**models.py**

```
class Student(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
        surname=models.CharField(max_length=200)

       class Meta:
             managed=False
             db_table='student'

class Group20(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    math=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)
    english=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)

    class Meta:
        managed=False
        db_table='group20'

class Nondemandgroup(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    acting=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)  
    cooking=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)

    class Meta:
        managed=False
        db_table='nondemandgroup'
```

i receive the following message :

```
OperationalError at /class101/

(1054, "Unknown column 'group20.student_id' in 'field list'")
```

what is the cause? how to fix it ?

I fisrt removed class meta : `managed:"False`" it indeed implemented migrations however still recive that  `OperationalError at /class101/` .

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it has run makemigrations and migrate with no problem.

Comment: if like so, you should check the table schema in database directly, and ensure it has the column concerned.